# How to create a column and fill it with new values based on a separate columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that has a no_employees column that is a str object. whats the best way to create a new column (company_size) in the data frame and fill it with values based on the no_employees column like in the example below

```
mental_health_df = pd.read_csv("Mental Health.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
mental_health_df.head(100)

no_employees        company_size
                 |
6-25             |Small
More than 1000   |Extremely Large
500-1000         |Very Large
26-100           |Medium
100-500          |Large
1-5              |Very Small
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please bin using [df.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)

```
 import numpy as np
df['company_size']=pd.cut(df['no_employees']. astype('category').cat.codes*10,[-np.inf,9,19,29,39,49,np.inf], labels=['Very Small','Large','Medium','Very Large','Small','Extremely Large'])
print(df)

    no_employees     company_size
0            6-25            Small
1  More than 1000  Extremely Large
2        500-1000       Very Large
3          26-100           Medium
4         100-500            Large
5             1-5       Very Small
```

**How it works**

```
#Converted no of employees to codes but for ease of defining bins multiplied by ten
  df['no_employees']. astype('category').cat.codes*10

#Decided to bin using df.cut
pd.cut(df['no_employees']. astype('category').cat.codes*10,\
       [-np.inf,9,19,29,39,49,np.inf], labels=['Very Small','Large','Medium','Very Large','Small','Extremely Large'])
```

Comment: Could you explain what the  [-np.inf,9,19,29,39,49,np.inf] part is doing please?

Comment: This defines the bins, categories within which the provided info should be devided.. As per documentation it `Defines the number of equal-width bins in the range of x`, np.inf==positive infinity and -np.inf== negative infinity